# Timecomplexity with given input and time

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What's the easiest way to get the time-complexity of a function when the input and time per input is given?

For example:

```
n    | 10  20  40  80  160  320   640
time | 1   3   9   60  475  3732  29835
```

How could I find the time-complexity of this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, you are interested in polynomial complexities (*O(n)*, *O(n<sup>1.5</sup>)*, *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* ...).

The easiest way to estimate the time-complexity of your function implementation would be to look at the last two largest datapoints.

You doubled (*2) the input size *n* from 320 to 640.
And your execution time increased by a factor of 8 (29835/3732 =7.994...).

Thus, your time complexity estimate is *O(n<sup>3</sup>)* since 2<sup>3</sup>=8.
One should pay attention, that this estimate is correct only if you tested it on large enough datasets (*n* is large) and your lower-order terms do not influence a solution significantly anymore. Moreover, this is a time-complexity of your implementation of the algorithm, not the algorithm itself.

Another useful technique to understand the complexities of your code would be plotting them (*t* versus *n*) on a log-log plot. Since the degree of the polynomial determining the complexity will become just the slope of the line on log-log plot, that can give you an understanding of what the complexity is and if you reached the asymptotic region or not. In addition, such plots can give you an idea of your lower order terms, log-terms and etc.

However, usually, you know what is the supposed complexity of the algorithm by some theoretical analysis, and then you may compare your actual timings to the theoretical prediction. That allows to avoid a lot of pitfalls during the estimation process.